# Python adds x0 to integers

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and am getting this small problem. I am using Python 3.3

There is a variable I declared in my code

```
file_name = "resource\email\ham\6.txt"
```

However, when I look for the variable, it appends additional numbers

```
>>file_name
'resource\\email\\ham\x06.txt'
```

Is there a reason why it behaves as so? If not, how do I remove those additional characters? Also, why are they there?

Comment: Backslashes are *escape sequences*. Double the backslashes or use a raw string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Use `r` raw string:

```
file_name = r"resource\email\ham\6.txt"
```

Double `\`:

```
  file_name = "resource\\email\\ham\\6.txt"
```

Or `/`:

```
file_name = "resource/email/ham/6.txt"
```

`\` has a special meaning in python, it is used to [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: Alright! This makes a lot of sense now